# Achieving the same result without paddingLeft property

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Total Pregnancies"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="160dp"
            android:text="Full Term"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="75dp"
            android:text="11"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="190dp"
            android:text="Premature"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="12"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Multiples"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="85dp"
            android:text="16"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="160dp"
            android:text="Living"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="95dp"
            android:text="17"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Ab Included"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="70dp"
            android:text="13"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="160dp"
            android:text="Ab Spontaneous"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="14"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="190dp"
            android:text="Ectopics"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:text="15"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how the screen looks, can anyone tell me how can i achieve this layout. i have come up with the layout, but it seems it does not fit for all screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `LinearLayout` width `fill_parent` to use the entire width of the screen.
Then for each `TextView`, set the `layout_width` to 0dp, and set `layout_weight` to the proportion of the screen you want that view to have.

In the padding, specify the minimum amount you want between the different cells.

For example, if you want the text to occupy double the space of the numbers, use the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Total Pregnancies"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Full Term"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="11"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Premature"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="12"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can u help me out in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132404/relative-layout-text-field-not-gets-properly-aligned

Answer (score 1):

Use TableLayout
Here is [an example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/)

Comment: +1, even [`GridLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) will do.

Comment: You can add fixed space space, by using layout_marginLeft. You can adjust the width by the screen width by using layout_width="0dp" and layout_weight="1"