# Relative layout text field not gets properly aligned

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_firstandLastName"            
            android:layout_weight="1.20"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Street1"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_street1"            
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="E-Mail"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_email"            
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Gender"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_gender"            
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.40"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Street 2"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_street2"            
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.20"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="SSN"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_ssn"            
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.20"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="DOB"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_dob"            
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="City"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_city"            
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.30"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Religion"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_religion"   
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Phone"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_phone"            
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.15"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="State"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_state"            
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Race"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_race"   
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Mobile"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_mobile"            
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.35"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Zip Code"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_zipCode"            
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.15"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Ethnicity"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_ethnicity"   
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am having a problem where i have to map something like this uniform.

```
Name: "Kevin"        State: "VA"        Email: "Kevin@Kevin.com
```

But may layout seems to be mess up when i try to see the output in emulator, attached is the screen shot of the same. Can anyone tell me what is exact space i should be giving to make it uniform across.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your rows to be aligned the same way, make sure that you give the same weight to each `TextView`, on each one of the `LinearLayout`s.

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_firstandLastName"            
            android:layout_weight="1.20"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Street1"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_street1"            
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Gender"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_gender"            
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.20"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Street 2"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facesheet_detail_street2"            
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice that "Name" and "Gender" `TextView`s have the same weight, since I want them to be aligned. Same with the second `TextView` of each `LinearLayout`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, wish i was there with u for a beer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the properties

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/idOfViewToAlignWith"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/idOfViewToAlignWith"
```

to align edges of `Views`

You also have properties such as

```
android:layout_alignCenter
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Look through the [RelativeLayout Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) to see which properties best work for you

Also, that's a whole lot of `Views`. I would suggest commenting out all but one or two rows and columns and start with a minimum amount of `Views` until you get them right so you aren't constantly changing a lot of them. You may also have to play with the `padding` a little after using these new properties. Since these are nested in `LinearLayouts` you will want to use these properties in the parent `LinearLayouts`, obviously